# Do not recursion DNS queries

Tags: domain-name-system

Is it possible as a user to send a dns query and ask from the resolver to does not recursion the query?
I realized that it is possible on the Resolver server itself if you are managing it and I wanted to know if there is a flag that can be sent with “dig” that asks the Resolver not to recursion on the specific query I sent.
Thanks

Comment: And what purpose would that have exactly? You can ask directly the relevant authoritative server and it won't recurse.

Answer (score 1):

There is a flag `+[no]recurse`. See [man dig](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig)